# Git Post Commit hook get changed file into a variable

Tags: git, github, gitlab, githooks

Git Hook newbie here

I've a git post-commit hook and I'm getting changed file in. I want to get the filepath+filename (minus extension) in a variable. then pass this variable to a converter

```
#!/bin/bash
#.git/hooks/post-commit
# An example hook script that is called after a successful
# commit is made.
#
# To enable this hook, rename this file to "post-commit".

echo "post-commit started"
IFS=$'\n'
git diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD | grep '\.json$' |
while read file; do
   echo "$file"
   A="$file" | cut -d'.' -f 1
   #Don't get anything in A
   echo "$A"
   B="$A" +".html"
   #Don't get anything in B
   echo "$B"
   ## Python to convert goes here
   ## generate-schema-doc $A $B
 done
 echo "post-commit finished"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not about git hooks, but bash language.
First this line:

```
A="$file" | cut -d'.' -f 1
```

`$file` won't probably be a shell command and even if it were, you should instruct the shell that you want to actually execute it.

```
A=`echo "$file" | cut -d "." -f 1`
```

You have another error when joining `$A` and `.html`. You can simplify that with:

```
B="$A.html"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot will check this!